# How to iterate over lambda functions in Java

Tags: java, python, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I was able to do it in Python and my Python code is:

```
signs = {"+" : lambda a, b : a + b, "-" : lambda a, b : a - b}

a = 5
b = 3
for i in signs.keys():
    print(signs[i](a,b))
```

And the output is:

```
8
2
```

How do I do this same thing in Java through HashMap?

Comment: Java is only a very tiny bit more verbose

Comment: except that in python AFAIK lambdas are limited to a *single* statement, right?

Comment: @Eugene Actually, in Python `lambda`s are limited to no statements at all. Only expressions are allowed.

Comment: @WalterTross Oops. Values are literals, aren't they? :-/

Comment: Literals are values, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`BinaryOperator<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html) in this case like so :

```
BinaryOperator<Integer> add = (a, b) -> a + b;//lambda a, b : a + b
BinaryOperator<Integer> sub = (a, b) -> a - b;//lambda a, b : a - b

// Then create a new Map which take the sign and the corresponding BinaryOperator
// equivalent to signs = {"+" : lambda a, b : a + b, "-" : lambda a, b : a - b}
Map<String, BinaryOperator<Integer>> signs = Map.of("+", add, "-", sub);

int a = 5; // a = 5
int b = 3; // b = 3

// Loop over the sings map and apply the operation
signs.values().forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.apply(a, b)));
```

**Outputs**

```
8
2
```

---

Note for `Map.of("+", add, "-", sub);` I'm using Java 10, If you are not using Java 9+ you can add to your map like so:

```
Map<String, BinaryOperator<Integer>> signs = new HashMap<>();
signs.put("+", add);
signs.put("-", sub);
```

[Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/0XKbXs)

---

### Good practice

As already stated by [@Boris the Spider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015479/how-to-iterate-over-lambda-functions-in-java/52015508?noredirect=1#comment90981294_52015508) and [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52015479/how-to-iterate-over-lambda-functions-in-java/52015508?noredirect=1#comment91020754_52015508) in the comments, Its better to use `IntBinaryOperator` to avoid boxing, in the end your code can look like this :

```
// signs = {"+" : lambda a, b : a + b, "-" : lambda a, b : a - b}
Map<String, IntBinaryOperator> signs = Map.of("+", (a, b) -> a + b, "-", (a, b) -> a - b);
int a = 5; // a = 5
int b = 3; // b = 3
// for i in signs.keys(): print(signs[i](a,b))
signs.values().forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.applyAsInt(a, b)));
```

Comment: Thank you @BoristheSpider I don't work with `IntBinaryOperator` before, I will learn about this, I see your answer and find that you already using it +1

Comment: It's `(int, int) -> int` rather than `Integer` - so less boxing. Your answer is good though - +1!

Comment: If you're using java 10, it's OK to define the map as `var signs = Map.of("+", add, "-", sub);`

Comment: this is correct @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner make it without var to makes it more readable to the OP :)

Comment: Even with boxed values, you can use `BinaryOperator<Integer>` here, which is a subtype of `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`. Further, you don’t need to verbosely declare local variables for the functions: `Map<String, BinaryOperator<Integer>> signs = Map.of("+", (a, b) -> a + b, "-", (a, b) -> a - b);`; this is much closer to the OP’s Python code. Of course, whenever the use case allows to use `IntBinaryOperator` instead, it’s preferable, as it avoids boxing overhead (and is even shorter than `BinaryOperator<Integer>`)…

Comment: Thank @Holger I always learn from you, I edit my answer with your information, thank you very much

Answer (score 14):

Create yourself a nice, typesafe, `enum`:

```
enum Operator implements IntBinaryOperator {
    PLUS("+", Integer::sum),
    MINUS("-", (a, b) -> a - b);

    private final String symbol;
    private final IntBinaryOperator op;

    Operator(final String symbol, final IntBinaryOperator op) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.op = op;
    }

    public String symbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public int applyAsInt(final int left, final int right) {
        return op.applyAsInt(left, right);
    }
}
```

You may want a lambda that returns `double` rather than `int` for other operators.

Now, simply dump that into a `Map`:

```
final var operators = Arrays.stream(Operator.values())
        .collect(toMap(Operator::symbol, identity()));
```

For your example though, you don't need a `Map` at all:

```
Arrays.stream(Operator.values())
        .mapToInt(op -> op.applyAsInt(a,b))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Using:

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;
```